# Error using @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-rest

I'm developing a Spring Boot application where I'm trying to use the @PreAuthorize annotation to filter access to the User resource so that an User only can access to his own resource. Here is my UserRepository:

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MyUserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyUser, UUID> {
    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("principal.getId().equals(#uuid)")
    MyUser findOne(UUID uuid);

    MyUser findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

    MyUser findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

}
```

You can see the stack trace [here](http://pastebin.ca/3709016).

Somewhere in the stacktrace references the class WebSecurityConfig line 42. This is the method configureAuthentication of the following class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private BasicUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return authenticationTokenFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http

            // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
            .csrf().disable()

            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()

            // don't create session
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()

            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/myUsers").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH).authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();

        // Custom JWT based security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't have an implementation of MyUserRepository ?

Comment: Of course, you can see it in the first fragment of code,

Comment: This is an inferface, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, I'm using Spring Data Rest so it's not needed an implementation. Sorry, I didn't understand your first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Spring boot 1.4 has solved the problem.